# how to deal with categorial values in dataset to build mdoels

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, logistic-regression

I have a training dataframe `dfTrain` and the output of `dfTrain.head()` is shown below:

```
    C0 C1                              C2   C3 C4  C5               C6  
0   1  73                 Not in universe   0   0   0  Not in universe
1   2  58  Self-employed-not incorporated   4  34   0  Not in universe
2   3  18                 Not in universe   0   0   0      High school
3   4   9                 Not in universe   0   0   0  Not in universe
4   5  10                 Not in universe   0   0   0  Not in universe
```

There are total 38 features and they are both `categorical` and `numerical`. Ignoring `C1` and scaling numerical features, I am trying to build a **Logistic Regression** model. Since, the dataframe has `categorical` features, I am creating another dataframe which has dummy variables.

```
X = pd.get_dummies(dfTrain)
```

The shape of `X` now has 160 features which is much more than that of `dfTrain`.

Then I pass `X` and `y` (where `y` is target variable) to **Logistic Regression Classifier**

```
modelLogistic = LogisticRegression(C=10**-2, class_weight = 'balanced')

modelLogistic.fit(X, y)
```

The reason to use `class_weight = 'balanced'` is that there are 17 classes in `y` and highly imbalanced.

My question is: is my approach correct? Am I missing anything?

Comment: (1) The general approach of converting categorical vars to dummy-vars by adding columns/features is ok (2) 38->160 features is quite efficient. I trained models where the preprocessed data had 1M features (which is not a problem when the classifier supports sparse-matrices like LogisticRegression in scikit-learn) (3) The only thing i'm not sure about is the actual creation of X. It does not look like you select which columns should be processed (only the known categorical ones). But your code examples seem to miss some stuff, which would help understanding.

Comment: (4) I'm also not sure if passing a pd.DataFrame into scikit-learn is always valid. I usually go the way through df.as_matrix() there. Maybe it's even wise to check if sparse data-structures are used (which is not needed in your case because 160 features are not much).

Comment: @sascha thanks for your reply.  Could you please elaborate on your 3rd point. The way I am creating X is incorrect? I thought since dfTrain has all features, Pandas will automatically generate dummy features for Categorical features. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I would expect pandas to create dummy-features for all columns / unique values seen. Even the numerical-type columns (which is bad)!. The question is: are these columns still there or did you remove them first. If you removed them, they are not used in your fitting, because you overwrote X with the dummy-output and used it directly for fitting.

Comment: @sascha I checked thats not the case. dfTrain has 13 numerical features and 25 categorical features. When I use Pandas on categorical features only, I get 147 features and when I use it on entire dfTrain I get 160 features.

Comment: I see. The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) explain this behaviour. The defaults chosen in pandas might just work in your simple case. But you should check it. A column with only integers 1 and 2 for example will not be treated by default! (default only processes objects and categoricals; so probably just strings in your case; this is not the right thing to do 99.9% of times)